# hgrc extensions not working on mintty [WINDOWS]

Tags: bash, mercurial, cygwin

My company has Windows as their development environment so I'm trying to configure everything to work similar to my personal laptop (xubuntu). Currently I'm trying to get mercurial to display colours on commands such as `hg diff`. I edited my `mercurial.ini` file with the `color` extension and everything seems to be working fine on windows `cmd`. I have cygwin/mintty currently as my preferred bash shell but the colours aren't showing up on mintty. Any idea how to configure this?

Comment: currently when I `echo $TERM` I get `xterm`. How would I unset this?

Comment: `hg diff` still doesn't show colors after the unset. When I launch mintty again it's automatically set again?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Cygwin doesn't read `mercurial.ini`, but rather looks for a `.hgrc` file like a regular Unix terminal would. Try creating it and adding the corresponding settings there.

Keep in mind that Windows wants file extensions on every file, so creating a file `.hgrc` from Windows Explorer will likely create an incorrect one called `.hgrc.txt` instead.

Comment: I have added an `.hgrc` file as well and I'm sure that it's being read since it shows when I run `hg showconfig --debug'. It's read the color values from the file but just doesn't seem to be applying it.

Comment: I gave this a shot on my virtual Windows 8.1 machine running inside Ubuntu. When creating the `.hgrc` file from Explorer it ended up actually creating a file `.hgrc.txt`. This is not obvious unless you run `ls -a` from Cygwin, but after renaming it from Cygwin the colors appeared. Maybe that will work for you too? :)

Comment: defining `color` as `[extensions]` on `~/.hgrc` works for me

Comment: I have `color` defined already yet it only appears to be working on windows `cmd`. I created my `.hgrc` file through vim and it appears to be the right file type. I'll keep looking, thanks